# Masonry in WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-theming, masonry

Here's another attempt to get my posts into a grid:

**index.php** The page that loads all the posts.

```
<?php
get_header();?>

<div class="container">
    <?php get_template_part('includes/section','index');?>
</div>

<?php get_footer();?>
```

**section-index.php** Contains the pieces to display the image, title and excerpt.

```
<?php if( have_posts() ): while( have_posts() ): the_post();?>

<div class="grid">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('');?>" width="300" height="300"/>
    </div>
    <div class="title">
        <h2><?php the_title();?></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="excerpt">
        <?php the_excerpt();?>
    </div>
    <div class="read">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">read more</a>
    </div>
</div>

<?php endwhile; else: endif;?>
```

**app.scss** `.grid` groups the pieces together, `.container` positions all the posts.

```
.grid {
  background: pink;
  max-width: 17%;
  float: left;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
}
```

The problem here is that I can't figure out how to center the entire grid together because the `.container` causes the footer to be ignored and bounces back up under the header.

## Alternative Method: Using WordPress built in Masonry

Here's what I've managed to achieve to get the masonry working. I am using the same code within `index.php`.

**masonry.js**

```
(function( $ ) {
    $(function() {
        var container = document.querySelector('.js-masonry');
        var msnry;
        imagesLoaded( container, function() {
            msnry = new Masonry( container, {
                itemSelector: '.item-masonry',
                isFitWidth: true
            });
        });
    });
});
```

**app.scss**

```
.js-masonry {
  border: solid 5px green;
      position: relative;
      max-width: 1080px;
      margin: auto;
      padding: 10px;
}

.js-masonry:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.item-masonry {
  border: solid 5px pink;
}
```

**section-index.php**

```
<div class="js-masonry">
    <?php if( have_posts() ): while( have_posts() ): the_post();?>
        <div class="item-masonry">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><img src="" width="310" height="310"></a>
            <h2><?php the_title();?></h2>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; else: endif;?>
</div>
```

The masonry works, but:

1. The `.item` inside the `.js-masonry` is leaning on the left side rather than within the center, resulting a huge space on the right side.
2. I'm unable to get the gutter working by adding it within `masonry.js`. I want even space between all the `.item`.

Any solution on how I can resolve these two problems?

Comment: You should rethink using `columns` and use CSS Grid to do this.

Comment: OK, I’ll give it a go. I looked up about what you said, looks like it’s much better and simple to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out that `masonry.js` needed `columnWidth:`.

For the styling, I had to add:

```
.js-masonry {
  border: solid 5px green;
  max-width: 860px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.js-masonry:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.item-masonry {
  width: 180px;
  float: left;
}
```

I had to ensure the widths are appropriate for item and grid.

```
padding: 0px 20px 0px  0px;
```

Since `gutter`  isn’t working for me in WordPress, I added this for item to get even space without relying thin and thin transparent borders.